# CSV time series subset selection and Data agregation

Tags: python, matlab, csv

Here is a portion of a table:

```
21 , F    ,  -59981 , 2015-05-08 00:00:04 , F1
21 , P    ,       1 , 2015-05-08 00:00:04 , Shed
21 , P    ,       7 , 2015-05-08 00:00:05 , PowerS
21 , P    ,       0 , 2015-05-08 00:00:05 , PowerG
21 , P    ,     205 , 2015-05-08 00:00:05 , Panel1
21 , P    ,     129 , 2015-05-08 00:00:05 , Panel2
21 , P    ,     145 , 2015-05-08 00:00:05 , Panel3
21 , V    , -120789 , 2015-05-08 00:00:05 , VrmsA
21 , V    , -120746 , 2015-05-08 00:00:05 , VrmsB
21 , I    ,   -1750 , 2015-05-08 00:00:05 , I11
21 , I    ,    -319 , 2015-05-08 00:00:05 , I12
21 , I    ,    -988 , 2015-05-08 00:00:05 , I21
21 , I    ,    -512 , 2015-05-08 00:00:05 , I22
21 , I    ,   -1790 , 2015-05-08 00:00:05 , I31
21 , I    ,    -131 , 2015-05-08 00:00:05 , I32
21 , F    ,  -59994 , 2015-05-08 00:00:05 , F2
21 , F    ,  -59982 , 2015-05-08 00:00:05 , F1
21 , P    ,       2 , 2015-05-08 00:00:05 , Shed
21 , P    ,       6 , 2015-05-08 00:00:06 , PowerS
21 , P    ,       0 , 2015-05-08 00:00:06 , PowerG
21 , P    ,     205 , 2015-05-08 00:00:06 , Panel1
21 , P    ,     129 , 2015-05-08 00:00:06 , Panel2
21 , P    ,     146 , 2015-05-08 00:00:06 , Panel3
21 , V    , -120750 , 2015-05-08 00:00:06 , VrmsA
21 , V    , -120708 , 2015-05-08 00:00:06 , VrmsB
21 , I    ,   -1748 , 2015-05-08 00:00:06 , I11
21 , I    ,    -318 , 2015-05-08 00:00:06 , I12
21 , I    ,    -986 , 2015-05-08 00:00:06 , I21
21 , I    ,    -512 , 2015-05-08 00:00:06 , I22
21 , I    ,   -1794 , 2015-05-08 00:00:06 , I31
21 , I    ,    -132 , 2015-05-08 00:00:06 , I32
21 , F    ,  -60018 , 2015-05-08 00:00:06 , F2
21 , F    ,  -59982 , 2015-05-08 00:00:06 , F1
```

I would like to manipulate a table in CSV via Matlab or Python such that every second Panel1 Panel2 Panel3 get aggregated for example

```
21 , P    ,     205 , 2015-05-08 00:00:05 , Panel1
21 , P    ,     129 , 2015-05-08 00:00:05 , Panel2
21 , P    ,     145 , 2015-05-08 00:00:05 , Panel3
```

would give T1=205+129+145
And table of T1, T2, T3 can be formed. The aggregate data can be added to another CSV file. 
Also is there an easy way to plot all Panel1  or Panel 2 separately in matlab or python?

Comment: output should be another csv file?

Comment: yes output should be in another csv file

Comment: T2=205+129+146,what about T3?

Comment: This list continues, I just put a portion of the table and it is a coincidence that T1 and T2 are equal. So T3 happens at the 7th second.

Comment: Tell me if it's working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import csv


with open('thef.csv', 'rb') as f:
    data=list(csv.reader(f))

a= [int(i[2].strip()) for i in data if "Panel" in i[4]]

b=[sum(a[i:i+3]) for i in range(0,len(a),3)]

print a

print b
"""
Output:
[205, 129, 145, 205, 129, 146]
[479, 480]"""

myvars=[]
#my vars to generate variables T1,T2
for i in range(1,len(b)+1):
    myvars.append('T'+str(i))
print myvars

myrows= map(list,zip(myvars,b))

print myrows

with open('test.csv', 'wb') as fp:
    myf = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')
    myf.writerows(myrows
```

)